# incompatible types in assignment of const char* to char

Tags: c++, class

So I trying to build this program that will take two **char** and a **double**. Once the user has input the information. I will transfer the information to an object by using the function below.
But every time I try to compile i get this error *incompatible types in assignment of const char* to char [20]*. Can anyone give me a hand and clarify when im not understanding. Thanks in advance.

```
void Molecule::set(const char* sym, const char* type, double weighT);
```

And this how I call it.

```
molecule[i].set(symbol, description,weight);
```

And within the set() function I just have to transfer the values inpputed to my private member in my object which i did by using **this->** function.

////So This part is supposed to transfer the value to my Class Molecule private members////

```
this->symbol_ = sym;
this->type_ = type;      
this->weight_ = weighT;
```

///////Here is my Class Molecule////////

```
class Molecule{
private:
    char symbol_[20];
    char type_[20];
    double weight_;
public:
    void set(const char* sym, const char* type, double weighT);
    void display() const;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `strcpy` or similar to copy the strings from your `char *` to your class's `char []`. Using `=` is attempting to copy the pointer but they are indeed incompatible types.

Answer (score 0):

symbol_ is a char[], you need to use stcpy to fill it.
In set method :

```
   this->symbol_ = sym;
```

should becomes

```
  stncpy(this->symbol_, sym, 20);
```

Or simpler define symbol_ as an std::string replacing :

```
  char symbol_[20];
```

with

```
  std::string symbol_;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
this->symbol_ = sym;
this->type_ = type;
```

is invalid. Arrays have no the copy assignment operator. You should use either standard C function strcpy or strncpy that are declared in header `<cstring>`

For example

```
std::strncpy( this->symbol, sym, 20 );
this->symbol[19] = '\0';
std::strncpy( this->type, type, 20 );      
this->type[19] = '\0';
```

Also it is a good idea to assign a name for magic number 20 either using an enumerator or static constant.

Also instead of character arrays you could use standard class std::string that has several overloaded assignment operators.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers and Arrays are not the same thing, although it is easy to believe that they are.
Arrays can be passed as arguments to functions that request pointers because of *pointer decay*, and that can lead people to believe that they are interchangeable.

See this article: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

When you declare `symbol_[20]`, this tells the class to allocate 20 bytes when the object is created. `symbol_` will *always* point to this allocation. You cannot reassign it as you could with a pointer.

You probably will want to copy the text pointed to by `sym` using `std::strncpy`. Be careful, though. If the string pointed to by `sym` is bigger than 19 characters (19 + 1 for the null character at the end), then you will need to terminate your symbol_ array with a null character (\0) manually for it to be a valid string.

```
#include <cstring>
...
std::strncpy(symbol_, sym, sizeof(symbol));
symbol_[19] = '\0';
```

I didn't get the chance to compile the code above, so, it might be best to study the example at the end of this article:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/?kw=strncpy